# Node.js connection to mysql database callback functions not executed

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect my node.js application to a mySQL database, but it seems like the callback functions of `con.connect()` and `con.query()` are not executed.
This is the connection part of my code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
           host: "localhost",
           user: "user",
           password: "pass",
           database: "db",

    });

app.get('/timetracking/dbTest', (req, res) => {
    var error1;
    var r;



    con.connect(function(err){
        s = 3;
        res.send(err);
    });

    var s = 1;

    con.query("SELECT * FROM Employee", function (err, result, fields) {
        error1 = err;
        res.send("yes");
        r = result;
        s = 2;
    });
    if (error1) res.send(error1 + "fail");
    else res.send(r + "ok" + s);
});
```

The App is starting normally and I can view the site in my browser, but the result I get is "undefinedok1". That means that the value of the send variables don't get changed in the callback functions. The mysql module is installed. Furthermore, I'm getting no error messages if I enter e.g. a invalid password for the DB user. I cant imagine why they don't get changed.

Comment: Callbacks are not synchronous - for example the `var s = 1` line will run right after `con.connect` but before the callback has (maybe) finished - it's asynchronous.  You have to chain the work in each successive callback, or use something that makes it easier to manage (e.g. `async` functions and `await` them, or use promises)

Comment: This is a question with a lot of almost-duplicates on the site.  Some of them are old and will recommend the `async` library but that usage is mostly out of favor with promises/async/await

Comment: Ok thank you, so its the wrong way of exporting the select result into a variable I guess. I will search for a solution for that. I was just wondering because of no errors at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback code runs asynchronously from the rest of your method.  You need to run the code in each successive callback, or use async/await or promises.

The simplest adjustment with your existing code (freehanded, may have syntax errors):

```
app.get('/timetracking/dbTest', (req, res) => {
    var error1;
    var r;

    con.connect(function(err){
        s = 3;
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }

        var s = 1;

        con.query("SELECT * FROM Employee", function (err, result, fields) {
            error1 = err;

            r = result;
            s = 2;

            if (error1) res.send(error1 + "fail");
            else res.send(r + "ok" + s);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Found a solution myself, but this should work too. Thank you for the async tip! I totally forgot about that one.